# Getting item position from cursor adapter

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-cursoradapter

Hello I Need Help on Getting the item position by using a cursor adapter but its not working an error occurs and I get : Cannot Be Cast Error.

Please Help Any Help Would be appreciated

**AlbumFragment**

```
public class AlbumFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,OnItemClickListener{


private Album mAlbum;


private AlbumAdapter mAdapter;
GridView gridview;

@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_album, container, false);
   mAdapter = new AlbumAdapter(getActivity(), null);
    gridview = (GridView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

   getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
   return myFragmentView;
 }


@Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   gridview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}






@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {      
    String select = null;  

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {
            /* 0 */
            BaseColumns._ID,
            /* 1 */
            AlbumColumns.ALBUM,
            /* 2 */
            AlbumColumns.ARTIST,
            /* 3 */
            AlbumColumns.NUMBER_OF_SONGS,
            /* 4 */
            AlbumColumns.FIRST_YEAR,
            /* 5 */
            AlbumColumns.ALBUM_KEY
    }, null, null, AlbumColumns.ALBUM);
   }  


@Override
public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position,
        final long id) {
    Cursor cursor = mAdapter.getCursor();



    NavUtils.openAlbumProfile(getActivity(), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AlbumColumns.ARTIST)),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AlbumColumns.ALBUM)), cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID)));

}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {  
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);  
}  



@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {  
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);  
}  
}
```

**AlbumAdapter**

```
public class AlbumAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


private final LayoutInflater mInflater1;

 public AlbumAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    mInflater1=LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {


    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    if (holder == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.albumTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.albumgrid);
        holder.artistName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artistgrid);
        holder.coverAlbum = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icongrid);
    }view.setTag(holder);


    String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AlbumColumns.ARTIST));
    String albumname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AlbumColumns.ALBUM));

    long albumId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID));


      final Uri ART_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ART_CONTENT_URI, albumId);
        holder.coverAlbum.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.default_artwork);
        Picasso.with(context).load(albumArtUri)
        .into(holder.coverAlbum);

holder.albumTitle.setText(albumname);
holder.artistName.setText(artist);}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView albumTitle;
    TextView artistName;
    ImageView coverAlbum;

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
              (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.griditemlayout, parent, false);
}
}
```

**Album**

```
public class Album {

    /**
     * The unique Id of the album
     */
    public long mAlbumId;

    /**
     * The name of the album
     */
    public String mAlbumName;

    /**
     * The album artist
     */
    public String mArtistName;

    /**
     * The number of songs in the album
     */
    public int mSongNumber;

    /**
     * The year the album was released
     */
    public String mYear;

    /**
     * Constructor of <code>Album</code>
     * 
     * @param albumId The Id of the album
     * @param albumName The name of the album
     * @param artistName The album artist
     * @param songNumber The number of songs in the album
     * @param albumYear The year the album was released
     */
    public Album(final long albumId, final String albumName, final String artistName,
            final int songNumber, final String albumYear) {
        super();
        mAlbumId = albumId;
        mAlbumName = albumName;
        mArtistName = artistName;
        mSongNumber = songNumber;
        mYear = albumYear;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) mAlbumId;
        result = prime * result + (mAlbumName == null ? 0 : mAlbumName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + (mArtistName == null ? 0 : mArtistName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + mSongNumber;
        result = prime * result + (mYear == null ? 0 : mYear.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Album other = (Album)obj;
        if (mAlbumId != other.mAlbumId) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!TextUtils.equals(mAlbumName, other.mAlbumName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!TextUtils.equals(mArtistName, other.mArtistName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (mSongNumber != other.mSongNumber) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!TextUtils.equals(mYear, other.mYear)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mAlbumName;
    }

    }
```

**LogCat**

```
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner cannot be cast to com.ray.mimp.model.Album
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at com.ray.mimp.fragment.AlbumFragment.onItemClick(AlbumFragment.java:87)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1282)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3181)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3932)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
12-06 09:36:23.335: E/AndroidRuntime(29125):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks For Any Help

Comment: Very minor thing: Some of these comments are unnecessary and decreases readability. `public long mAlbumId;` is pretty self-explanatory of what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Invoking `CursorAdapter.getItem(position)` returns the cursor that contains the data moved to the correct position](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#CursorAdapter.getItem%28int%29). Because it returns a Cursor, you cannot cast it to an Album. Instead, you need to query the cursor like what you did in `AlbumAdapter.bindView()`